# The "right" way to do stored procedure parameter validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have a stored procedure that does some parameter validation and should fail and stop execution if the parameter is not valid.

My first approach for error checking looked like this:

```
create proc spBaz
(
  @fooInt int = 0,
  @fooString varchar(10) = null,
  @barInt int = 0,
  @barString varchar(10) = null
)
as
begin
  if (@fooInt = 0 and (@fooString is null or @fooString = ''))
    raiserror('invalid parameter: foo', 18, 0)

  if (@barInt = 0 and (@barString is null or @barString = ''))
    raiserror('invalid parameter: bar', 18, 0)

  print 'validation succeeded'
  -- do some work
end
```

This didn't do the trick since severity 18 doesn't stop the execution and 'validation succeeded' is printed together with the error messages.

I know I could simply add a return after every raiserror but this looks kind of ugly to me:

```
  if (@fooInt = 0 and (@fooString is null or @fooString = ''))
  begin
    raiserror('invalid parameter: foo', 18, 0)
    return
  end

  ...

  print 'validation succeeded'
  -- do some work
```

Since errors with severity 11 and higher are caught within a try/catch block another approach I tested was to encapsulate my error checking inside such a try/catch block. The problem was that the error was swallowed and not sent to the client at all. So I did some research and found a way to [rethrow](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2007/12/01/how-to-rethrow-errors-in-t-sql.aspx) the error:

```
  begin try
    if (@fooInt = 0 and (@fooString is null or @fooString = ''))
      raiserror('invalid parameter: foo', 18, 0)

    ...
  end try
  begin catch
    exec usp_RethrowError
    return
  end catch

  print 'validation succeeded'
  -- do some work
```

I'm still not happy with this approach so I'm asking you:

How does your parameter validation look like? Is there some kind of "best practice" to do this kind of checking?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't think that there is a single "right" way to do this.

My own preference would be similar to your second example, but with a separate validation step for each parameter and more explicit error messages.

As you say, it's a bit cumbersome and ugly, but the intent of the code is obvious to anyone reading it, and it gets the job done.

```
IF (ISNULL(@fooInt, 0) = 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Invalid parameter: @fooInt cannot be NULL or zero', 18, 0)
    RETURN
END

IF (ISNULL(@fooString, '') = '')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Invalid parameter: @fooString cannot be NULL or empty', 18, 0)
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you have used IF (ISNULL(@fooString, '') = '') rather than IF (@fooString is null)?

Comment: @macleojw: He checks for null and '' at the same time.. clever :)

Comment: The second validator has invalid syntax: 'RAISEERROR'. There should be just one 'e'. Funny is that in English it is correct as 'raise+error' has double 'e' but not in MS SQL language.

Comment: You should use SET NOCOUNT ON and SET NOCOUNT OFF

Answer (score 1):

We normally avoid raiseerror() and return a value that indicates an error, for example a negative number:

```
if <errorcondition>
    return -1
```

Or pass the result in two out parameters:

```
create procedure dbo.TestProc
    ....
    @result int output,
    @errormessage varchar(256) output
as
set @result = -99
set @errormessage = null
....
if <errorcondition>
    begin
    set @result = -1
    set @errormessage = 'Condition failed'
    return @result
    end
```

Comment: Raiseerror is unpredictable (might continue execution!) and not eveyr client deals with it in the same way.  A perl client could die!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to return out as soon an possible, and see not point to having everything return out from the same point at the end of the procedure.  I picked up this habit doing assembly, years ago.  Also, I always return a value:

```
RETURN 10
```

The application will display a fatal error on positive numbers, and will display the user warning message on negative values.

We always pass back an OUTPUT parameter with the text of the error message.

example:

```
IF ~error~
BEGIN
    --if it is possible to be within a transaction, so any error logging is not ROLLBACK later
    IF XACT_STATE()!=0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
    END

    SET @OutputErrMsg='your message here!!'
    INSERT INTO ErrorLog (....) VALUES (.... @OutputErrMsg)
    RETURN 10

END
```

Comment: I want to use the sproc within another sproc and want to do as little error checking as possible so raising an error and catching it in the outer sproc seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: some day when this procedure is called from another location, I hope they remember to catch the errors too.  I think it is best to catch the all errors as they happen, deal with them locally, and return back appropriate info.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this answer history I followed this question and accepted answer, and then proceeded to 'invent' a solution that was basically the same as your second approach.

Caffeine is my main source of energy, due to the fact that I spend most of my life half-asleep as I spend far too much time coding; thus I didn't realise my faux-pas until you rightly pointed it out.

Therefore, for the record, I prefer your second approach: using an SP to raise the current error, and then using a TRY/CATCH around your parameter validation.

It reduces the need for all the IF/BEGIN/END blocks and therefore reduces the line count as well as puts the focus back on the validation.  When reading through the code for the SP it's important to be able to see the tests being performed on the parameters; all the extra syntactic fluff to satisfy the SQL parser just gets in the way, in my opinion.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're copying my second approach and even  reinvented the rethrow-SP I originally used?

Comment: @VVS - oh dear you're right!  It wasn't deliberate, I read through the question and through the answers. Then, due to lack of sleep I promptly forgot the whole gamut of options displayed here and initially went for the if/begin/end result then 'discovered' this approach - forgetting that this is one of the options you had tried.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

I always use parameter @Is_Success bit as OUTPUT. So if I have an error then @Is_success=0. When parent procedure checks that @Is_Success=0 then it rolls back its transaction(with child transactions) and sends error message from @Error_Message to client.

Comment: Hm, that makes only sense, if the SP's return value is used otherwise. Or is there a good reason why not just do "RETURN x"?

Comment: You always have two possibilities for errors: SQL error (eg XML parsing) and logical (eg constraint error). If you do not make difference between them, you lose control over application behaviour. If you log errors outside SQL, eg in filesystem, then your application should get error type.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code for validation in mySQL stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_payment;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_payment
(
    payment_id INT,
    amount DECIMAL(5,2),
    date DATE
)

BEGIN 
    IF amount <= 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '22003' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Amount should not be less or qual to zero' ;
    END IF;
    UPDATE payments p
    SET p.amount = amount,
    p.date = date
    Where p.payment_id = payment_id;
END $$

delimiter ;
```